Expansion of Gram Matrix
I am hoping to expand
$$
({\bf A}+c)^{\bf T} ({\bf A}+c) - {\bf A}^{\bf T} {\bf A}
$$
Where ${\bf A}$ is a square matrix
and $c$ is a constant value added to every matrix element.
If I consider ${\bf C}$ as a matrix with the same dimensions as ${\bf A}$ with constant elements $c$, I know how to attack this problem because
I know matrix multiplication expands:
$$
({\bf A}+{\bf C})^{\bf T} ({\bf A}+{\bf C}) = ({\bf A}+{\bf C})^{\bf T} {\bf A} ~+ ~({\bf A} +{\bf C})^{\bf T} {\bf C}
$$
And transpose as well :
$$
({\bf A}+{\bf C})^{\bf T} = {\bf A}^{\bf T} + {\bf C}^{\bf T}
$$
Note for square matrices we have ${\bf C}^{\bf T} = {\bf C}$ so
$$
({\bf A}+{\bf C})^{\bf T} = {\bf A}^{\bf T} + {\bf C}
$$
giving
$$
\begin{align}
({\bf A}+{\bf C})^{\bf T} ({\bf A}+{\bf C}) &= \left({\bf A}^{\bf T} + {\bf C}\right) {\bf A} ~+~ \left({\bf A}^{\bf T} + {\bf C}\right) {\bf C} \\
\\
&= {\bf A}^{\bf T} {\bf A} + {\bf C} {\bf A} + \left( {\bf A}^{\bf T} + {\bf C} \right){\bf C}
\end{align}
$$
So
$$
({\bf A}+c)^{\bf T} ({\bf A}+c) - {\bf A}^{\bf T} {\bf A} = {\bf C} {\bf A} + \left( {\bf A}^{\bf T} + {\bf C} \right){\bf C}
$$
But I feel like I'm missing some basic properties of the matrix product and transpose, and I'm wondering if there's any easier way to do this by considering $c$ the constant instead of ${\bf C}$ the constant matrix

Thanks to @Theo Bendit and @Exodd 's comments, we define ${\bf J}$ as a matrix of ones, and further expand using ${\bf C} = c ~{\bf J}$:
$$
\begin{align}
{\bf C} {\bf A} + \left( {\bf A}^{\bf T} + {\bf C} \right){\bf C} &= {\bf C} {\bf A} +  {\bf A}^{\bf T} {\bf C} + {\bf C}^2 \\
&= c \left( {\bf J} {\bf A} +  {\bf A}^{\bf T} {\bf J} \right) + c^2 n
\end{align}
$$
Since the elements of ${\bf C}^2 = c^2 n $ and we are just adding ${\bf C}^2$.
And since ${\bf J}$ = ${\bf J}^{\bf T}$,
$$
{\bf J} {\bf A} +  {\bf A}^{\bf T} {\bf J} = {\bf J} {\bf A} +  {\bf A}^{\bf T} {\bf J}^{\bf T}
$$
And we know (${\bf X} {\bf Y})^{\bf T} = {\bf Y}^{\bf T} {\bf X}^{\bf T} $
So
$$
{\bf J} {\bf A} +  {\bf A}^{\bf T} {\bf J}^{\bf T} = {\bf B} + {\bf B}^{\bf T}
$$
Where ${\bf B} = {\bf J} {\bf A}$.
giving
$$
({\bf A}+c)^{\bf T} ({\bf A}+c) - {\bf A}^{\bf T} {\bf A} = c ({\bf B} + {\bf B}^{\bf T}) + c^2 n
$$

How do you propose to add a matrix and a scalar?

@TedShifrin Elementwise addition. Every matrix element plus the scalar.

@TedShifrin I tried to edit my question to make it more directed on what I'm looking for. I think it was poorly writtent the first time, sorry about that.

As a suggestion, write $\mathbf{A} + c$ instead as $\mathbf{A} + c\mathbf{J}$, and specify that $\mathbf{J}$ is the matrix where every element is $1$.

as a way to simplify more, $C = cee^T$ where $e$ is the vector of all ones, and if you call $v^T = e^TA$, you get a new expression (remember that $e^Te = n$)

@Exodd ahh I think I see what to do. Just to make sure I'm not making a mistake, did you mean $C = \frac{c}{n} e e^T$ when you wrote $C = c e e^T$?. Edit, nevermind. In your definition $e$ is the vector of all ones, I was thinking it was the matrix of all ones this whole time
